# Get deployed service endpoint url from wso2 registry

Tags: registry, wso2, application-server

Is there any way to get deployed service endpoint url from registry on application server. When I deploy service on application server it appears in Governance Registry admin console service list, and all information about its endpoints is avaliable too. But I need to get endpoint url programmatically on application server to make communication between services.

Answer (score 0):

You can get endpoint data using governance API methods. Please refer [1] how to user governance API to get endpoint data.

1. http://wso2.org/library/articles/2010/09/governance-api-wso2-governance-registry

Comment: Yes, I have found this solution. But WSO2 Application Server has no governance api in its libraries. I use maven and when I pack aar archive, its size become more than 100MB. Without this dependecy size of archive is about 8MB. As for me it is not right. Version of WSO2AS is 5.0.0